# When rewriting URLs, query parameters are empty

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to make it so that `$_session['kw']=$_GET['kw']`.

If I use the url `index.php?kw=example`, then when i `echo $_GET['kw']` i get a blank.  Is there anything that would cause `$_GET` to not work?

I figured out that it must be caused by the .htaccess file there are rewrite rules in there that go like this:

```
RewriteRUle ([-a-z0-9_]+)_review.php review.php?id=$1
```

These probably conflict with the `$_GET`.
I need to rewrite these rewrites, but how?

Comment: Even if I take everything else out of the file, the $_GET comes up empty.  Am I going crazy?

Comment: I am doing rewrites, is that a problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're using a version of PHP that's 8 or more years old? ;)

Comment: URL Rewriting is a problem if you're doing it *wrong*, yes.

Comment: Ok the rewrites in htaccess look like this: 
RewriteRule number1_review.php$ review.php?id=number1 
How can I make these work with $_GET?

Comment: This is now an apache question, but you need the `[QSA]` suffix on th RewriteRule to add GET parameters from the original request onto the new request. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to put [qsa] on the rewrite rules to append the query string.  Thanks for bearing with me!